# Is it possible to add a custom image in the info pane in mapkit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I am trying to add a custom image for the info pane in google map once a user clicks on a marker. I can't find anything in the MKAnnotation class.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's MapCallouts code sample demonstrates how do do this with the callout and their Weather Map sample shows how to do custom annotation views. There documentation is really excellent and these samples are both helpful.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009491